# Increment perticular field by 100

Tags: shell-script

I have a file where the below line is for 4000 times, with some others lines also.

```
:32A:151021JPY301,
```

I need to replace the first occurrence of this to  `:32A:151021JPY5000`,  and then subsequent occurrence incrementing by 60 at the end. That means output will be,

```
:32A:151021JPY5000,
:32A:151021JPY5060,
:32A:151021JPY5120,
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: If you show us what you have tried to do so far, I'm sure people would be happy to help you wherever you're stuck.  SE, however, is not intended to be a script writing service so you'll have to show us what you've done to solve it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

Found a straight solution for this. Can you please try...

 `cat test_file|sed 's/JPY301/JPY/g'|awk 'BEGIN {count=4940} count+=60 { print $1count}'`

*for example*
$ cat test_file|sed 's/JPY301/JPY/g'|awk 'BEGIN {count=4940} count+=60 { print $1count}'
:32A:151021JPY5000
:32A:151021JPY5060
:32A:151021JPY5120
:32A:151021JPY5180
:32A:151021JPY5240
:32A:151021JPY5300
:32A:151021JPY5360
:32A:151021JPY5420
:32A:151021JPY5480
:32A:151021JPY5540
:32A:151021JPY5600